# I have to contain two models with json field value in cakphp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

[log table with product id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh4Dq.png)
[product table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8WrP.png)
**My Log tables contained data field having json data like**

```
{"product-id":"14","product-name":"test","product-url":"\/projects\/test\/products\/lecture-details\/8","product-type":"lecture","product-price":"0"}
```

**I want to join products table with the product id stored in data file.How can I do that?**

log table "product-id": "14" this field need to be contained with product table.

```
$getQuery = $this->Log->find('all')->matching('Users', function ($q) { return $q->where(['Users.is_deleted' => 'n']);})->contain(['Users','Products'])->select(['user_id' => 'Users.id', 'username' => 'Users.username','fname' => 'Users.fname','lname' => 'Users.lname', 'email' => 'Users.email','view_date' => 'Log.dt_created_on','data' => 'Log.data'])->where($conditions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add this code Log association model**

```
$this->hasOne('Products', [
      'className' => 'Products',
      'foreignKey' =>false,
      'conditions' => array("Products.id=JSON_VALUE(cast(log.data as nvarchar(256)),'$.\"product-id\"')")
]);
```

Comment: It Doesn't work on the server.

SQL Error [207] [S0001]: Invalid column name '$.product-id'.

Comment: You should just cast the data type.